# In Gatsby, using Wordpress as a data source, create different pages with different templates

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api

I have a Gatsby site that is pulling data from another Wordpress site. It creates pages dynamically fine for posts but as soon as I add a new custom post type, it only creates pages for this one, but not the posts. So basically, it only creates pages for the latest post I add to the "gatsby-node.js" file. Which looks like this:

```
const path = require(`path`)
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  return graphql(`
    {
      allWordpressPost(sort: { fields: [date] }) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            excerpt
            content
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    result.data.allWordpressPost.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.slug,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
        context: {
          // This is the $slug variable
          // passed to blog-post.js
          slug: node.slug
        },
      })
    })
  })
}

//Create a page for each Property Post type
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  return graphql(`
    {
      allWordpressWpProperty {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
            title
            content
            featured_media {
              localFile {
                childImageSharp {
                  original {
                    width
                    height
                    src
                  }
                  }
              }
            }
            acf {
              size
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    result.data.allWordpressWpProperty.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.slug,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/property.js`),
        context: {
          // This is the $slug variable
          // passed to property.js
          slug: node.slug
        },
      })
    })
  })
}
```

The error I get is "cannot read "page" of undefined when I try to visit a blog post. Is there a way to create pages for both?

Answer (score 2):

So I don't think you should be exporting `createPages` twice.

Instead export it once and create pages for both types of post in the same function. You could easily abstract both into their own separate `async` functions and `await` them in `createPages`, just to give you that separation so you know what pages are being created each step of the way.

Something like this:

```
import createBlogPosts from "../somewhere";
import createPropertyPosts from "../somewhere";

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  await createBlogPosts({ graphql, createPage });
  await createPropertyPosts({ graphql, createPage });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding both queries under the same function and using the createPage function twice with the different results:

```
const path = require(`path`)
exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  return graphql(`
    query {
      allWordpressPost {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            excerpt
            slug
            link
          }
        }
      }

      allWordpressWpProperty {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
            title
            content
            featured_media {
              localFile {
                childImageSharp {
                  original {
                    width
                    height
                    src
                  }
                  }
              }
            }
            acf {
              size
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    result.data.allWordpressPost.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.slug,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
        context: {
          // This is the $slug variable
          // passed to blog-post.js
          slug: node.slug
        },
      })
    });

    result.data.allWordpressWpProperty.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.slug,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/property.js`),
        context: {
          // This is the $slug variable
          // passed to property.js
          slug: node.slug
        },
      })
    });
  })
}
```